# 2, 3, and 4 (a possible fixed point result ?)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, open-problems, banach-spaces

The question below is related to the classical [Browder-Goehde-Kirk fixed point theorem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38323269_An_elementary_proof_of_the_fixed_point_theorem_of_Browder_and_Kirk).

Let $K$ be the closed unit ball of $\ell^{2}$, and let $T:K\rightarrow K$
be a mapping such that
$$\Vert Tx-Ty\Vert _{\ell^{4}}\leq\Vert x-y\Vert _{\ell^{3}}$$
for all $x,y\in K$.

Is it true that $T$ has fixed points?

Comment: It would be easier to read if you just wrote `$\|Tx−Ty\|_4 \le \|x−y\|_3$`. It took me a minute to get the point of your question since I could barely see the difference between the supersubscripts

Comment: If that deserves a "-1", it's cool to me.


Comment: I don't think it does.  I just meant to make sure other readers could easily tell what you were asking; I didn't downvote and I hope I didn't encourage anyone else to.

Comment: Why did this question get a downvote?  Seems interesting to me.

Comment: For fun, I started considering variants of this question but made no real progress on them either. Let ${\bf FP}(p,q,r)$  be the same statement with $2,3,4$  replaced by $p,q,r$.  The BGK fixed point theorem gives us ${\bf FP}(p,p,p)$ for $1 < p < \infty.$  For what other values of $p,q,r$ can you prove or disprove this statement? Do you know of a counterexample to $FP(1,\infty, \infty)$?

Comment: BGK $\Longrightarrow$ FP$(p,q,r)$ for 1 < p $\leq$ r $\leq q< \infty $ ,
e.g.

Comment: @Ady: Since your question is whether or not $FP(2,3,4)$ holds, I'm confused.  You seem to be claiming that BGK resolves your question.

Comment: @Fabrizio Polo I'm not claiming that. Just that, e.g., $FP(2,4,3)$ holds, via BGK. Please read carefully my comment.

Comment: Would someone please state the classical Browder-Goehde-Kirk fixed point theorem?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: What are the related known results?

Comment: As far as I understood, the BGK (Browder-Göhde/Göbel-Kirk) fixed point theorem states that every non-expansive self-mapping on a non-empty, closed and convex subset of a uniformly convex Banach space has a fixed point.

Comment: $FP(p,p,\infty)$ is false for any $p$. We can let $(Tx)_i = x_{i-1}$ for $i<1$ and $(Tx)_0 =(1/2)( 1 - \sum_i x_i^2)$. Then $||Tx||_{\ell_2}^2 = (1/4)(1-||x||_{\ell_2}^2)^2+ x_{\ell_2}^2 \leq 1$ since $x_{\ell_2}\leq 1$ and, because each coordinate is a $1$-Lipschitz function in the $\ell_2$ norm, the whole thing is a $1$-Lipschitz transformation from $\ell^\infty$ to $\ell^2$.